# SwiftUI: How to use a linear gradient in a progress bar?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm trying to build a view that is a rounded rectangle in a bar chart, with a gradient that gets progressively darker the higher `value` is (value is on a 0-10.0 scale).  But I can't seem to figure how how to use `UnitPoint` here for endPoint to get the correct point where the gradient should end.  In other words if value = 5.0, I want the gradient to show the top of the bar as half way to the gradient's darkest color, or said another way the gradient's darkest color is always at 10.0 and the bar's color will only show as high as the bar is.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
            .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [ Color(UIColor(red: 0.98, green: 0.85, blue: 0.38, alpha: 1.00)) , Color(UIColor(red: 0.63, green: 0.02, blue: 0.11, alpha: 1.00))]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: CGFloat((value * 10 / 100)))))
            .frame(width: 40, height: open ? CGFloat(value * 10) : 0)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is to "mask" the gradient, rather than trying to calculate the `endPoint`.

Here's an example with 5 "bars" in an `HStack` - the first bar has a **max** value of `10`, then the bars' values go `9, 7.5, 5, 2`:

[image]

Sample code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct GradBars: View {
    
    var maxValue: CGFloat = 10
    
    var val1: CGFloat = 10
    var val2: CGFloat = 9
    var val3: CGFloat = 7.5
    var val4: CGFloat = 5
    var val5: CGFloat = 2
    
    @State var open: Bool = true

    let gradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [ Color(UIColor(red: 0.98, green: 0.85, blue: 0.38, alpha: 1.00)) ,
                                                               Color(UIColor(red: 0.63, green: 0.02, blue: 0.11, alpha: 1.00))]),
                                  startPoint: .bottom,
                                  endPoint: .top)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 8, content: {

                Rectangle()
                    .fill(gradient)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: open ? maxValue * 10 : 0, alignment: .bottom)
                    .mask(
                        VStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0).frame(height: val1 * 10)
                        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                    )
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(gradient)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: open ? maxValue * 10 : 0, alignment: .bottom)
                    .mask(
                        VStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0).frame(height: val2 * 10)
                        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                    )
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(gradient)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: open ? maxValue * 10 : 0, alignment: .bottom)
                    .mask(
                        VStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0).frame(height: val3 * 10)
                        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                    )
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(gradient)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: open ? maxValue * 10 : 0, alignment: .bottom)
                    .mask(
                        VStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0).frame(height: val4 * 10)
                        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                    )
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(gradient)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: open ? maxValue * 10 : 0, alignment: .bottom)
                    .mask(
                        VStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0).frame(height: val5 * 10)
                        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                    )
                
            })
        }
    }

}

struct GradBars_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GradBars()
    }
}
```